# Is there an easy-to-install website plugin for territory routing?

Tags: web-mapping, cartography, software-recommendations

For an application I'm creating, I want to be able to place dots on a map in locations that my users will be visiting.

Each user will have his own locations he has to visit, so I'd like to 'connect the dots' so to speak and color in the area inside the connected dots as his 'territory.' This information will be useful for the manager of these users so they he can see which areas are visited & unvisited so that he can better manage where the users need to visit.

(For example, having too many users in the same location might lead the manager to move some to another location so that more area is covered.)

I was looking for some kind of map plugins such as Google Maps APIs, any jQuery plugins, or other easy-to-incorporate library to incorporate in my website, which mostly uses the PHP framework CakePHP and uses jQuery as well. Does this exist anywhere? A simple Google search didn't yield anything impressive.

The closest thing I've found thus far is this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

The 'drawing' feature to connect the dots and color the area is perfect - unfortunately I cannot use Google Maps API as it's only free for products that don't charge users, and what I've developing will have a monthly charge. Is there anything similar to this out there?